# linux readdir - Are the entries "." and ".." always read first?

Tags: linux, directory, readdir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does readdir() guarantee an order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977441/does-readdir-guarantee-an-order)

I'm guessing this isn't the case, and I'd need to manually check the name of each entry instead of just skipping the first couple. Is that correct?

Comment: Related: [Does readdir() guarantee an order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977441/does-readdir-guarantee-an-order)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The POSIX standard does not guarantee anything about the order of directory entries whatsoever. As such, if you're interested in filtering out `.` and `..`, you do need to compare for them.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should never rely on finding `.` and `..` first (although it almost always happens).
I remember one case when I had problems with such an assuption (on ReiserFS they were not found first, but it was an old version of ReiserFS, now it may be different).

Answer (score 0):

It is not in the standard, but I have never seen them in any other place, but the first two. But, just in case, if you don't realy mind the time that much, I would do the check.