# Java - UnixFileSystem - how does list sort children?

Tags: java, linux, unix, filesystems

In Windows code `new File("").list()` sorts files by name.
In Linux (when **java.io.UnixFileSystem** is used) - files are sorted in some strange (but not random) way.
Is this behaviour adjustable? Or at least - which alghorithm is used to sort files ?

I cannot sort files in my code because I use some standard library that I cannot (or don't want) to modify - therefore don't offer to do this, please.

There are results for tomcat lib directory:

```
jsp-api.jar  
catalina-ant.jar  
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar  
catalina.jar  
jasper.jar  
ecj-4.2.2.jar  
catalina-tribes.jar  
servlet-api.jar  
tomcat-jdbc.jar  
tomcat-coyote.jar  
tomcat-api.jar  
tomcat-util.jar  
postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc3.jar  
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar  
catalina-ha.jar  
tomcat-dbcp.jar  
annotations-api.jar  
jasper-el.jar  
el-api.jar  
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
```

Comment: Strange but not random? Can you show an example?

Comment: added sample to the post for Tomcat lib directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that under the hood it's using `readdir` (or similar). So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8977490/683965) answer also applies here, basically it points to [this blog-post](http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/ReaddirOrder)