# Using dirent.h but files are being skipped

Tags: c++, loops, directory, dirent.h

I have several hundred images in a folder named: `1.jpg`, `3.jpg`, `4.jpg`, `6.jpg`, `8.jpg`, `10.jpg`, `15. jpg`, .... `100.jpg`, `102.jpg`, `103.jpg`, `113.jpg` etc...

I am using `dirent.h` to iterate through the files, but somehow `dirent.h` starts at `10.jpg` and the next file it delivers is suddenly `100.jpg` and then `102.jpg`, ... why does it skip some images?

```
int main (int argc, const char* argv[] )
{

cv::Mat image;

DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
if ((dir = opendir ("C:\\Users\\Faraz\\Desktop\\Project\\detecting_false_positives_stuff\\face_images\\faces\\")) != NULL) {
    ent = readdir (dir);
    printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
    ent = readdir (dir);
    printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
        printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);

        std::string fullPath = std::string("C:\\Users\\Faraz\\Desktop\\Project\\detecting_false_positives_stuff\\face_images\\faces\\") + ent->d_name;

        cout<<fullPath;

        image = cv::imread(fullPath);

        ...

    }
    closedir (dir);
}
return 1;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to sort the files yourself if you want them in order, `readdir` won't do that for you. See this also: [Does readdir() guarantee an order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977441/does-readdir-guarantee-an-order)

Comment: Ooh, so just the order is different? This means at the end I will still iterated through 1.jpg, 3.jpg etc..?

Comment: Looks like the files are sorted *alphabetically* by name, not by numeric.  Thus the order 1.jpg, 10.jpg, 105.jpg, 2.jpg.  If you want them in correct lexical order, prefix the numbers with zeros.