# Eclipse Virgo: Different startup order on Linux vs. Windows => How to fix?

Tags: java, linux, filesystems, startup, eclipse-virgo

The *AProMoRe* project is using an Eclipse Virgo server as the base. For the startup handling there are multiple ".plan" files to load the required artifacts. They are copied in the Virgo "pickup" folder and are named as follows:

- 100-manager.plan
- 101-portal.plan
- 102-filestore.plan

Note: In the same folder there are also other JAR and WAR files.

**Windows**: Everything startups perfectly. The first file that the hot deployer picks up after Virgo starts (*"KE0007I Virgo ready."*) is the first plan file (*"HD0001I Hot deployer processing 'INITIAL' event for file '100-manager.plan'."*). And then next next, and so on. All good.

**Linux**: The behavior is completely different. The plan files are only picked up later on during the loading and the hot deployer starts for some reason by just picking some of the JAR/WAR files to load first, leading to all kinds of resolution/dependency errors.

The same Virgo version (3.6.2.RELEASE) is used on both platforms, so my assumption was that the startup order/behavior should be the same.

Is the filesystem look-up behavior of Virgo (or Java in general) different of those platforms? Is there a fix/workaround to get a matching behavior?

Comment: There is no guarantee (in Linux at least. I'm not sure about windows. ) that readdir returns entries in a definite order. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977441/does-readdir-guarantee-an-order . Eclipse or Virgo or whatever it is should have logic to sort them if it wants ordered processing of files.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the plans into the repository folder and create a top-level plan which lists them all in the right order, then drop only the top-level plan into the pickup folder.